# Unemployment Rate Volatility

Tags: labor-economics

Is there a statistic that describes the “churn” in the unemployment rate i.e. how many became unemployed compared to how many found work?

I’ve heard of unemployment volatility (https://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/abs/10.1108/03068291211224937) but never could find any stat for it in the U.S.

For a better idea of what I’m talking about, here is an article written about it in India: https://www.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php?kall=warticle&dt=2017-10-31%2009:43:08&msec=273

Does the BoLS track this metric?

Answer (score 2):

The U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS rather than BoLS) publishes the results of its [Job Openings and Labor Turnover Survey](https://www.bls.gov/jlt/home.htm) (JOLTS)

For example, its [summary news release](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/jolts.nr0.htm) for May 2018, published on July 10, started with:

> The number of job openings edged down to 6.6 million on the last business day of May, the U.S. Bureau 
>   of Labor Statistics reported today. Over the month, hires and separations were little changed at 5.8 
>   million and 5.5 million, respectively. Within separations, the quits rate and the layoffs and discharges 
>   rate were little changed at 2.4 percent and 1.1 percent, respectively. This release includes estimates of 
>   the number and rate of job openings, hires, and separations for the nonfarm sector by industry and by 
>   four geographic regions.